# NPM showing error message after adding the Prop-Types in react project

Tags: node.js, reactjs, npm

This is the error message after I finished installation of Prop-Types Validation in my create-react-app

```
> burgerapp@0.1.0 start C:\Users\ajeet\Desktop\burgerapp
> node scripts/start.js

module.js:540
    throw err;
    ^

Error: Cannot find module 'webpack'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:538:15)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:468:25)
    at Module.require (module.js:587:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:11:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\ajeet\Desktop\burgerapp\scripts\start.js:19:17)
    at Module._compile (module.js:643:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:654:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:556:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:499:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:491:3)
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! burgerapp@0.1.0 start: `node scripts/start.js`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the burgerapp@0.1.0 start script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\ajeet\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2018-02-04T23_43_08_160Z-debug.log
```

Please help me to find solution. Thank you for your help.

Comment: The error message is clear. You need to install webpack. What did you do  for installation of Prop-Types Validation

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this just sometimes happens with npm when adding packages, especially with create-react-app projects. Delete node_modules and run npm install again, that should fix it.

Answer (score 1):

You can install webpack by using command 'npm install webpack --dev'.